# Using const int class member in typedef?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this whilst compiling with C++11:

```
class A{
    const uint32_t X = 5;
    typedef std::array<B, X> ARRAY;

};
```

and I get the error message

> Invalid use of non-static data member.

I don't wish to make this static because I had a few dynamic linking problems due to this and I don't wish to use initialiser lists because I would like these "magic numbers" to be very clear the top of the header.

Comment: `static constexpr`

Comment: I don't wish to use static because this was caused by a bug due to using static and dynamic linking.....

Comment: Even if you get it to work, If it's const, it will just be the same for every instance. Just wasted space that contains the value 5. It should be static.

Comment: And maybe you should ask about the linkage problem instead of asking about what you think is the solution to it, which isn't much of a solution.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, just settle on something :P

Answer (score 4):

The *very* old-fashioned way of doing this is to `#DEFINE X 5;` **Nobody uses this any more unless they want a slap on the wrist in the code review session.**

The *quite* old-fashioned way of doing this is to use `enum {X = 5};` In my opinion this is the best pre C++11 way.

The *modern* way of doing this is to use `static constexpr uint32_t X = 5;`

All these ways ensure that `X` is *compile-time* evaluable.

Comment: a `constexpr` member should be `static`, no?

Comment: Some not-so-old MS Visual Studio versions don't support `constexpr`; one could use `const` instead if compatibility with these versions is required.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is

```
class A{
    enum Array_Size : uint32_t { X = 5 };
    typedef std::array<B, X> ARRAY;

};
```

Comment: You don't need to make up any name for your `enum`. The simple syntax `enum: uint32_t {...}` is enough.